# Cannot use ng-Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, bootstrap-4

I cloned quickstart project from tour of heroes https://angular.io/guide/setup and I try to add ng-Bootstrap datepicker but it doesn't work. My project:

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { MyDatePicker } from './datepicker/my-datepicker.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, NgbModule.forRoot() ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, MyDatePicker ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  <my-datepicker></my-datepicker>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

my-datepicker.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbDateStruct} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

const now = new Date();

@Component({
    selector: 'my-datepicker',
    templateUrl: './my-datepicker.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './my-datepicker.component.css' ]
})
export class MyDatePicker {

    title: string = 'My datepicker';

    model: NgbDateStruct;
    date: {year: number, month: number};

    selectToday() {
        this.model = {year: now.getFullYear(), month: now.getMonth() + 1, day: now.getDate()};
    }

}
```

my-datepicker.component.html

```
{{ title }}

<p>Simple datepicker</p>

<ngb-datepicker></ngb-datepicker>
```

systemjs.config.js:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: {
          './*.js': {
            loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
          }
        }
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

But it doesn't work. The result I get is : [image]

it's very strange, why it looks so?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

After update index.html datepicker looks like well but now I can't bind ngModel and I got an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
zone.js:655 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ngb-datepicker'.
1. If 'ngb-datepicker' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-datepicker' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
<p>Simple datepicker</p>

<ngb-datepicker #dp [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="model" (navigate)="date = $event.next"></ngb-datepicker>

<hr/>
"): ng:///app/datepicker/my-datepicker.component.html@8:20 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ngb-datepicker'.
1. If 'ngb-datepicker' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-datepicker' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
<p>Simple datepicker</p>

<ngb-datepicker #dp [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="model" (navigate)="date = $event.next"></ngb-datepicker>
```

Comment: Are you loading bootstrap 4 css? :)

Comment: how to do it and where should I place these css?

Comment: update the `index.html` file

Comment: Easier way for that project is to add a tag on the html like any other html website.

Comment: Ok, I added to index.html but now I get an error: Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.
    at bootstrap.min.js:6

Comment: I said you to update the post with your index.html

Answer (score 0):

Refer the jquery script in your index.html file

```
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.x-git.min.js"
```

Before the bootstrap scripts as it is dependent on jquery

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by installing **Bootstrap 4 alpha** according to the **Dependencies** section of the [ng-bootstrap Getting Started Guide](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)

Here is the command you need to run on the same folder your package.json is located (but remember to read the link I posted above):

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 --save
```